# Letting buck test find libjvm.so in Buck managed C++ project

Tags: c++, jvm, java-native-interface, jnienv, buck

I am facing the following linker error in a Buck managed C++ project:

/usr/src/hbase/hbase-native-client/buck-out/gen/core/mini-cluster-test#compile-mini-cluster-test.cc.ob19eb5e6,default/mini-cluster-test.cc.o: In function `MiniCluster::create_vm(JavaVM_**)':

/usr/src/hbase/hbase-native-client/core/mini-cluster-test.cc:80: undefined 
reference to `JNI_CreateJavaVM'

In Makefile, I specified the following without effect:

LDFLAGS = -lprotobuf -lzookeeper_mt -lsasl2 -lfolly -lwangle -L/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server

libjvm.so is under /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server

Can someone give hint ?

Thanks

Comment: You said "In Makefile, I specified the following without effect:", but Buck doesn't use Makefiles, so this shouldn't correct this at all.  How are you building your project with Buck?